# Getting a variable from a website which is then stored

Tags: bash, shell, grep, jq

I need to retrieve the "message" variable from the website and store it in a variable.

Im new to shell script so im not sure how to do it. Ive been trying various ways for a while but they dont seem to work.

This is the output of the website example.web:8080/rest/message

```
[{"id":33,"message":"Dash","lastUpdated":1569922857154,"userName":null}]

#!/bin/bash
message=$( curl -# -L "http://example.web:8080/rest/message}")

username=$(
  <<< "${message}" \
  grep -P -o -e '(?<=<li>message: <strong>)(.*?)(?=<\/strong><\/li>)' |
  head -n 1
)
```

I need the message variable "Dash" To be stored which can be printer later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I am not sure if output you are getting is pure json or not, if you are ok with `awk` could you please try following(If you have proper json then please use jq or parser which is specially made for json parsing).

```
Your_command | awk -v s1="\"" '
match($0,s1 "message" s1 ":" s1 "[^\"]*"){
  num=split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),array,"\"")
  print array[num]
}'
```

EDIT: If you have `jq` tool with you, could you please try following(not tested).

```
curl -# -L "http://example.web:8080/rest/message" | jq '.[] | .message'
```

Comment: @Matas, you need to do `echo "$your_variable" | awk.....` command like that, did you try like that? It worked for me when I ran it.

Comment: `message | jq` - I think you are missing `"`.  :D

Comment: @KamilCuk, oh man, thanks for saving the day, cheers, thanks a TON :)

Comment: @Matas, Could you please let me know if this `jq` command worked for you?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yeah the command worked i edited it a bit. Thanks.export storedBanner=$(curl http://example.web:8080/rest/dashboardmessage | jq -r .[0].message|sed 's/<[^>]*>//g')  I used this to also remove any leftover HTML code :)

Comment: @Matas, great glad that it helped you. You could add that command in my solution for future reference of people. You could also select this answer as an correct one cheers.